# How do you log out of Stack Overflow (September 2014)

Tags: discussion, logout

How do you log out of Stack Overflow?  The log out button under the 'StackExchange' dropdown does not appear to log me out.  Nice feature for an expert programmers site.

I thought I should put the date in the title since they seem to enjoy changing the method of logging out regularly. Another nice feature there.

Comment: You may be confusing StackOverflow with the StackExchange network.  Logging out from StackOverflow will log you out from StackOverflow, but you may still be logged in on other StackExchange websites.

Comment: Why would you want to leave, Chris? You're one of us now, Chris. Come back inside, return to your seat, and let us never speak of this again.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Chris has only one account in StackExchange for StackOverflow. I guess thats not the case here

Comment: Yes, apparently once you are in they don't want you to leave.  Tried deleted all passwords stored in browser but that did not seem to be the solution either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are logged in to the site,  the logout button appears below stackExhange.. or else go the url https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout

Comment: yes, one would think that would be the way to log out of this site.  However, I've tried that numerous times without luck.

Answer (score 2):

So this seemed to work.  Perhaps I was just getting frustrated and did not click the second log out button.  I guess clicking one 'log out' button seemed just a bit too simple.

[image]

[image]